# Registering a Standalong app in the Application Launcher of KDE

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, application

First off, I am using Kubuntu 12.04.

I've just downloaded and unpacked a standalone installation of some software (Intellij's Phpstorm IDE, but I don't think it matters). I've copied the unpacked directory to my `/opt` directory using sudo.

I am able to launch the main shell script from the commandline without using `sudo` with no issues.

---

I would like to run the app from my `Application Launcher` so, I ran the `Edit Applications...` app from the Launcher icon and added the path to the main shell script in a new entry (`/opt/PhpStorm-111.344/bin/phpstorm.sh`) and saved it. Whenever I click the newly added entry, nothing happens, the application does not launch. I have seen [this question about registering applications in kde](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20342/how-to-register-application-in-kde), and I don't think it applies to this situation since that is what the `Edit Applications...` dialog is supposed to do (I think).

So what am I missing? Do I need to specify another way of running the command in the dialog entry? Is this a `.desktop` file issue? Something else?

I ran the command `/opt/PhpStorm-111.344/bin/phpstorm.sh` from the `ALT+F2` *run* box , invoking a terminal. I was returned with a message complaining that the `$JAVA_HOME` variable cannot be found.

Now, I do indeed have a `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable setup in my `.bashrc` file, and it can be seen from an `echo $JAVA_HOME` command. Again, I am able to run the application with no problems if I simply open a terminal and run the shell script from there, so the `$JAVA_HOME` variable is seen in that context. I have logged out and back in and run `source ~/.bashrc`, and neither seem to help.

I am thinking now it is some sort of user permission issue to the `$JAVA_HOME` variable that is preventing it from running.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you run it *without* `sudo`?

Comment: Yes I can run the same shell script from the commandline *without* using `sudo`

Comment: [Don't set environment variables in `.bashrc`, that's not what it's for.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your display/xsession manager is set up, `~/.bashrc` may not be sourced before `startkde` is called, so if that's where you're setting up `$JAVA_HOME`, nothing on your KDE desktop may see it.

Helpfully, `startkde` is set up to source `*.sh` from every directory in `kde4-config --path lib | tr : '\n' | sed -n -e 's,/lib[^/]*/,/env/,p'`.  This likely contains `~/.kde4/env` or similar, so if you want a variable to be present KDE-sessionwide, just drop a shell script with an `export` in there.

Comment: That was the issue. Once I added an appropriate reference for the `JAVA_HOME` variable to the `~/kde/env/` directory (its `~/kde`, not `~/kde4` on my system for some reason), I could start the program appropriately. Great answer, Thanks @ephemient.

Comment: @HariSeldon KDE's default is to use `kde`, but some distributions changed it to `kde4` to allow parallel installability between KDE3 and KDE4.  I wasn't sure what you were running.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple workaround that involves a 2 line script. It simply re-exports the `$JAVA_HOME` variable to the appropriate path, and then invokes the application's main shell script. Repointing the KDE Application Launcher to this new script launches the application as expected.

I'm still not sure why I need to do this though, since I can plainly see the correct `$JAVA_HOME` variable definition outside of the context of my contrived script. So if anyone can shed light on why that might be occurring, I would happily mark that as the appropriate answer for this question.

Comment: Good diagnosing - I tend to set up environment in `/etc/environment` which is loaded by `pam_env.so` regardless of how I log in, so I might not have thought of this.