# How can I correct errors in the KDE Start Menu/Launcher?

Tags: kde, chrome, kubuntu

For whatever reason, whenever I try to launch Google Chrome via the KDE Start menu, I get this error:

> KDEInit could not launch '/usr/bin/google-chrome-beta'

The thing is, I don't have `google-chrome-beta` ... I only have `google-chrome`, which I can launch from a shell window.

Q: How can I convince the KDE Start Menu that I only want to launch `google-chrome` instead of `google-chrome-beta`?

If I then right-click my running Google Chrome in the taskbar, and select "Show a Launcher When Not Running" and quit Google Chrome, I get a launcher that links to `google-chrome-beta`.

Q: How can I edit and fix a broken launcher?

One day I managed to fix things: The KDE menu was launching `google-chrome` correctly. I forget how I made that happen. Shortly after that, my Google Chrome launcher changed into a Chrome Web Store Payments launcher, which neither manages to launch anything nor, for the life of me, can I figure out how to remove it, so I have this dumb broken launcher icon stuck permanently to my KDE.

Q: How can I remove a broken launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a clue from a similar question: [Registering a Standalong app in the Application Launcher of KDE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36414/registering-a-standalong-app-in-the-application-launcher-of-kde)

**The trick is to launch an application called "Application Finder"**

Therein I was able to change the Google Chrome Beta to be Google Chrome.

To remove the Google Web Store Payments launcher, I right-clicked to edit the panel. Upon hovering over the Web Store Payments icon, there was a little red X that allowed me to remove it.